# unable to use fields in my URL with mssql server report builder

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

So here's the situation. I'm coding a Report in mssql Server report builder and I want one of my tablix text box to contain a clickable link to presumably a C# razor application.

what I've been trying to do is make a link which contains a query string that sends ID over to the RazorApplication which looks something like this right now.

```
<a href=https://localhost:54455/RazorApp?guid=Fields!ID.Value>PDF</a>
```

the server and link up until /RazorApp? works, but I need to send the ID along for validation.

The purpose of the application is to get the ID from the query string, cross reference that with the database and then get the corresponding Varbinary(max) value which I then convert back to the PDF it originally was and open it. but in order for that to work, i need to be able to send the ID along.

I have tried using these HTML5 tags which produce this error

[image: Error]

using the 'go to URL' function gives the same error even without the HTML tags.

so the big question here is. what are my possibilities in sending over the ID which is a GUID to my application?

Answer (score 0):

On SSRS, you can specify the URL using an expression. Right click the text box in your tablix you want to become a hyperlink and select `Text Box Properties`. Select the `Action` Pane and then the `Go the URL` Radio Button. Click the ***f*x** button. Your expression will then (likely) be something like:

```
="https://localhost:54455/RazorApp?guid=" & Fields!ID.Value
```

That should then work.

Comment: It does see it as an exprresion now so that's a start but it won't see it as a clickable link now.

Comment: @BoAlsemgeest What do you mean by "won't see it as a clickable link"? If it's a hyperlink, then it is "clickable".

Comment: i can now click on it. but when i do so i get this error in the browser:

The item '/Fields!ID.Value' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)

Comment: That means nothing on it's own, I'm afraid. Is the link taking you to the correct page? If so, the error on the page you've navigated to, not the hyyperlink.

Comment: instead of taking me to the application running on the localhost it takes me to the report server:     http://presalesvm/ReportServer?%2FFields!ID.Value&guid=%22%20

as the %22%20 shows it gets the space and & sign but it doesnt run the field!ID.Value

Comment: Considering that your URL is `localhost` that URL would take you to whatever service is running on your local machine on port 54455. If it's linking to the Report Server, then you've not used Go To URL.

Comment: oke so i got it work @larnu but whenever i use the quotations around the url it doesnt see it as url anymore. now i only need to figure out a way so it will send the Value of ID instead of litteraly outputting Fields!ID.Value in my browser